# Unicity of solution of $\inf_{d\in X}\{\langle z,d\rangle:\||d\|| \leq 1\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

Let (X, ⟨·, ·⟩) Hilbert space y ∥ · ∥ the induced norm by the inner product
⟨·, ·⟩ in X. For a element z $\in$ $X/{0}$. Consider the problem

$\inf_{d\in X}\{\langle z,d\rangle:||d|| \leq 1\}$

Show that for all $z\neq 0$, the problem has a unique solution.

I have already proved the existence of the solution by the Weiertrass theorem, but I still have to prove the uniqueness of the solution. I have tried to show it by the common method: By contradiction, let us assume that there exists $d_{1},d_{2}\in B(0,1)$ such that

$\inf\{\langle z,d_{1}\rangle\} = \inf\{\langle z,d_{2}\rangle\} = \alpha$

I have tried to play with the properties of the norm and the definition of the problem, but I have not yet come to a contradiction that is clear to me. ¿Can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: How does the Weierstrass theorem apply here. The closed unit ball is not necessarily compact.

Comment: I use a generalized version of the weiertrass theorem, which is as follows: Let $X$ Hilbert Space and $f:X\longrightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be proper, lower semicontinuous in the weak topology and coercive. Then, the problem val(P) $= \inf_{x\in X}f(x)$, it follows that val(P) $\in\mathbb{R}$ and sol(P) $\neq\emptyset$, in other worlds, P have solution.

Comment: If you are willing to use such machinery, it seems a little strange that you have difficulty showing uniqueness. The key fact is that the closed unit ball is strictly convex.

Comment: I know you could use what you used, but this was an exercise in class before that content (convexity). It is worth noting that the above theorem is used to prove what you have said. Besides, I need to practice to get used to it, i tries to use the paralelogram law to prove it, but did not achieve a good result

Comment: I added an elementary answer below.

Comment: @copper.hat My answer does not use orthogonal decomposition or any other idea. It just uses **deifintion** of inner product. I think it is more elmentary than your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d$ be any solution. Let us show that $d=-\frac z {\|z\|}$. First note that $ \langle z, d \rangle \leq \langle z, -\frac z {\|z\|} \rangle$. This gives $\langle z, d \rangle \leq -\|z\|$. Now $\|z+\|z\|d\|^{2}=\|z\|^{2}+\|z\|^{2}\|d\|^{2}+2 \Re \langle z, \|z\|d \rangle\leq 0$. Hence $d=-\frac z {\|z\|}$.

Incidentally, it is easy to check that $-\frac z {\|z\|}$ is indeed a solution, so existence is also proved.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying to me. I have some question, by intuition I know that $\alpha = ||z||$, but I was trying to prove the problem without knowing how to get the value of the function (you assumed the value of $\alpha$). Is there a way to solve it without knowing the value of $\alpha$ and $d$ explicitly?

Comment: @Pocoyo No, I did not assume that the infimum is $\|z\|$. I have deleted that useless sentence from my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but could you clarify why $d$ is unique?. I can't understand it.

Comment: @Pocoyo I took **any** solution $d$ and proved that $d$ cannot be anything other than $-z/\|z\|$. That proves uniqueness, right?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I was thinking of doing it all by contradiction to show uniqueness, sorry for taking up your time and patience. It is quite clear to me.

Comment: @Pocoyo Glad I could help.

Comment: +1 @geetha290krm After thinking about it for a while I am not that sure which answer to prefer, I just found the use of the orthogonal decomposition very intuitive, on the other hand you are right in that you use even a bit less machinery and the most "minimal" approach might be seen as the best

Answer (score 2):

Any $d \in X$ can be written uniquely as $d = \alpha z+ y$, where $y \bot z$. Then $\|d\|^2 = \alpha^2 \|z\|^2 + \|y\|^2$.

Then $\langle z, d \rangle = \alpha \|z\|^2$. If $\|d\| \le 1$ then the corresponding $\alpha$ can have values in the $[-{1 \over \|z\|}, {1 \over \|z\|}]$, and hence the $\min$ value of $\langle z, d \rangle$ is $-\|z\|$. If $\langle z, d \rangle = -\|z\|$, then we must have $y=0$.

In particular, the minimising $d$ is unique.

Comment: +1 the orthogonal decomposition is a beautiful approach I think

Comment: @PeterMelech My answer uses only the definition of inner product.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sure, it is fine too. I just prefer this one for its clarity and the concept of orthogonality is still quite elementary, a matter of taste may be...